# Laravel eloquent arrays to remove matching

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I have to two eloquent returned arrays :

```
$services = \App\Service::all();
$userService = \App\UserService::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

What i tried is that :

```
@foreach($services as $service){

    @foreach($userServices as $userService){
        @if($userService->service_id != $service->id)
            <option value="{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->name }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

But its repeating the options, And creating mess.

What will be a good approach ?

Comment: What is the relationship between Service and User? is it many to many?

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis There is no User its `UserService`, and the relationship is One to One. means one userservice have one service.

Comment: you retrieving data twice. uservice is enough to what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
$userServices = \App\UserService::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->pluck('service_id')->toArray();

$services = \App\Service::whereNotIn('id',$userServices)->get();

//Now you can loop through services 
@foreach($services as $service){

    <option value="{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->name }}</option>

 @endforeach
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested relations in your model. Like this;

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function user_service()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(UserService::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And Controller

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$services = Service::with(['user_service' => function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
}])->get();

return view('page', compact('services'));
```

Answer (score 0):

i have read the code

```
$services = \App\Service::all();
$userService = \App\UserService::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

and

```
  @foreach($services as $service){

  @foreach($userServices as $userService){
      @if($userService->service_id != $service->id)
          <option value="{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->name }}</option>
      @endif
  @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Userservice is sufficient to what you want to do, no need to retrieve data twice. you can simply find all service for the logged user in you query
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

```
return Service::with(['user_service' => function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
}])->get();
```

or try to make a inner joins with raw query.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your approach just change `!=` to `==`

```
@if($userService->service_id == $service->id)
```

Or if you want a good approach try eloquent.

Your models seems to be many to many relationship

Visit this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many